# Converting iso8601 date to unix timestamp in java

Tags: java, datetime, iso8601

I have a date string

```
   String s = "2014-09-01T19:22:43.000Z";
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(s);
```

But I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-09-01T19:22:43.000Z"
```

How do I convert the above string to unix timestamp?
Thanks

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`X` is used for `ISO 8601 time zone` in `SimpleDateFormat`, not `Z`

Correct format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`

Comment: Scratch that. `X` parses `Z` as Zulu.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

> How do I convert the above string to unix timestamp?

```
Instant.parse( "2014-09-01T19:22:43.000Z" )
       .getEpochSecond()
```

## java.time

The `java.time.Instant` class can parse your input string with its standard ISO 8601 format. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-09-01T19:22:43.000Z" );
```

To get a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970:

```
long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

For whole seconds since epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z:

```
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Be aware of **possible data loss** when going to milliseconds or whole seconds. The java.time classes have nanosecond resolution, so any microseconds or nanoseconds present in the value will be truncated.

## Joda-Time

**Update** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

The Joda-Time library makes this work easier. Your [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string can be fed directly to a Joda-Time constructor. The built-in parser expects ISO 8601.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-09-01T19:22:43.000Z" ) ;
```

## Unix Timestamp

What do you mean by a Unix timestamp? Some people mean a count of whole seconds since the first moment of 1970 [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (the Unix [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))) while ignoring leap seconds (see [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). Some people mean a count of milliseconds or other resolution.

Note the use of a `long` primitive rather than the more common `int`.

For milliseconds, call `getMillis()`.

```
long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = dateTime.getMillis();
```

For whole seconds, divide by 1,000. Consider if you want rounding or truncation of the fractional seconds.

---

Normally I would suggest passing a DateTimeZone object along with your string to the DateTime constructor. But no need if all you want is a count since epoch.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).